# Problems with 4K videodownloader app (Ubuntu Studio 19.10)

Tags: upgrade, gui, 19.10, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10.

The last two upgrades of the App "4K videodonwloader" (January, 2020) have a several mayor GUI problem: It is not usable.

As you can see in the screen captures, the GUI shows the panels in a wrong way.

[image]

That first GUI view is already wrong. There are some parts and buttons of the original image missed.

[image]

That second GUI view is when I put some link related with a YouTube video (but, it is the same whatever the source was).

As you can see, the panel is full unreadable and not useful at all. You cannot to see the buttons with all the download alternatives.

So...

What's wrong, here?

How can we fix this?

Why the older versions worked so fine and these news don't?

Comment: Is this an application included in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Hi, Erich! Not. it is not an Ubuntu repositories app. BTW: I found another app, in the Ubuntu repositories, to make the same job.

Comment: Excellent. The reason I asked is because we don't support applications that are outside of the Ubuntu repositories.